# running slow effects on legs

Tags: running, workout-routines, legs

I have just started running, I have noticed, that whenever I run at a slow pace, I noticed that my legs feel very painful, but whenever I run like those runners on olympics(full burst) I don't feel as much stress in the legs as I have when I run slowly. What should be the proper way to run? Is it wrong for me to run like at full speed at all times? I do feel more comfortable running, it's just I look like an idiot running really fast while other runners are running at a slower pace.

Comment: Not as an answer to your question, but don't bother what others think; Especially if you are building on your body. From a mathematically point of view: you will always pass more people that have a slower pace and run longer than people that run shorter with a higher pace.

Comment: "I run like those runners on olympics" is meaningless, the Olympics has a lot of running events, ranging from 100m sprint to entire marathons, with totally different paces. Are you doing sprints or just running at a relatively fast pace? What are you training for and what are your goals? Doing sprints all the time isn't going to help much if your goal is to run a marathon.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist I'm training to run the 10k under the least time possible. Sadly my training is all wrong as I like to run it at full sprint till I run out of juice,but I don't know really, I just want to run and run when I'm doing it. Are there ways for me to run sprints all the time but maintain enough juice for a marathon?

Comment: @marchemike Sprints and distance running are totally different. You need to train for what you want to do - if you want to run a 10k, or a marathon, you'll need to train to run long distances *by running long distances*. You can't build up the stamina and develop the ability to pace yourself by doing max effort sprints in short bursts.

Comment: My advice would be to go and see somebody who can analyse the way you're running and diagnose why it's painful. Rather than just sprinting because that doesn't hurt, solve the underlying issue and then do the proper training to achieve your goal.

Comment: I do recall on a few long (for me) training runs with a friend who's slightly slower, I found that I had to shorten my stride in order to match pace, which was remarkably uncomfortable. Putting in only a marginal increase in effort made me feel much better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say you are new to running so first and foremost your body takes time to adapt. Your running action will also be slightly different running at slow speed than when running fast or sprinting. I find I tend to have a more slouched posture when on slow runs than I do when running at race pace. It could possibly have something to do with your trainers too. Get a gait analysis done and make sure you're wearing the correct trainers for your running style. As for 10k training, you need to vary your training as @Anthony Grist sys. Mix long slower runs with shorter, more intense intervals or speed work on a track. Bit the best advice I can give you is build up gradually. Don't do too much too soon. I was very enthusiastic when I started running so made that mistake and ended up having all sorts of problems with my knees and constantly feeling in pain. There isn't really a 'one size fits all' answer when it comes to running as everyone is different. Just listen to your body and find out what is best for you. You will soon improve over time as your body adapts and you will be able to do more without feeling tired or having aches and pains